# Java exceptions using finally

Tags: java, exception, finally

I am study exceptions in Java and came across this snippet:

```
public class Test
{
    public int b()
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.println("try block");
            return 0;
        }
        finally
        {
            System.out.println("Finally block!");
        }
     }

     public static void main (String[] args)
     {
          Test t= new Test();
          t.b();
     }
}
```

Since the finally block is always executed and in this case you have a return 0 before it, will it still be executed? (What exactly would the output be).

Comment: Only one way to find out.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis ummm. Let me guess. Try it out?? :)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Technically there are two ways: run the code or read (and understand) the specs!

Comment: @assylias My bad, I meant to say one **easy, simple, impossibly obvious** way to find out.

Answer (score 2):

Compliation eRROR AT

```
System.out.printlnI"Finally block!");
                   ^
                  here
```

:-)

Comment: I guess you never made a typo :))

Comment: @user3126119 Error is always an error even if it is a typing error  :-)

Comment: thanks for your help anyway, I figured it out ;) and *comp*i*lation :)